# What is the rich text box called in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, richtextbox

I'm doing a mac/cocoa project and I can't find out how to do a richtextbox in mac, I need to find out the class name.

For example; text box is NSTextField and button is NSButton, anyone know about rich text box? I know I could've googled this, but I don't know what to google for, since if I use richtextbox it will only bring me dozens of windows articles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[NSTextView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 3):

> I don't know what to google for, since if I use richtextbox it will only bring me dozens of windows articles.

[site:developer.apple.com rich text view](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=site%3adeveloper.apple.com%20rich%20text%20view&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

If you find your Google results are flooded by links to unrelated programming environments, adding `site:developer.apple.com` to the query is always a good first attempt to filter them. `site:stackoverflow.com` is also often worth a try.

Comment: Or “cocoa rich text view” (though the first hit for that one right now is a Cocoa Touch hit, not a Cocoa hit).